# Mock out http request of service class in a jasmine test

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine, ngxs

I was under the impression that you could just spy on services in jasmine using the spyOn method. And then return a value once that method is called. But maybe that's too simplistic of a thought?

I would like to test the following nxjs action:

**./Auth.state.ts**

```
  // ...

  @Action(Login)
  login(ctx: StateContext<AuthStateModel>, action: Login) {
    return this.authService.login(action.payload).pipe(
      tap(({ accessToken }: { accessToken: string }) => {
        const {exp} = jwt_decode(accessToken);
        const expiresAt = dayjs().add(exp, 'second');
        ctx.patchState({
          token: accessToken,
          username: action.payload.username,
          expiresAt
        });
      })
    );
  }
```

That action depends on the authService login method:

./auth.service.ts

```
  // ...

  login({ username, password }: User): Observable<{ accessToken?: string }> {
    return this.http
      .post(`${api.BASEURL}${api.API_LOGIN}`, { username, password });
  }
```

Now my test is as follows:

**./Auth.state.spec.ts**

```
describe('Auth', () => {
  let store: Store;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [NgxsModule.forRoot([AuthState]), HttpClientTestingModule],
      providers: [HttpClient, HttpHandler, AuthService]
    });

    store = TestBed.inject(Store);
  });

  function setupState(NEW_STATE = null) {
    store.reset({
      ...store.snapshot(),
      auth: NEW_STATE
    });
  }

  describe('login', () => {
    it('sets the state when login is successful', () => {
      // TS2345: Argument of type '"register"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
      spyOn(AuthService, 'login').and.returnValue(false);

      // read an workaround for it here: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/9675 
      // Object.defineProperty(AuthService, 'login', { get(){ return false; } });
      // but also no luck...

      const expectedState = { token: null, username: 'Some username', expiresAt: null };
      setupState();
      store.dispatch(new Login({ username: expectedState.username, password: '' }));
    
      const auth = store.selectSnapshot(state => state.auth);
      expect(auth).toEqual(expectedState);
    });
  });
  // ...
```

Comment: You can definitely use [spys](https://angular.io/guide/testing-components-scenarios#testing-with-a-spy) to mock HTTP calls. That being said, you need to make sure you are returning actual `Observable` if you service is using HttpClient. `returnValue(false)` is not `Observable<boolean>`. You can use RxJS `of` to return an `Observable`, as in `spyOn(AuthService, 'register').and.returnValue(of(false));`. Also why don't you just use a spy to mock `login` of AuthService in the same way?

Comment: Ty. You're right. The 'register' method should've been 'login'. Changed it. Accepted the answer below with the TestBed injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Auth.state.spec.ts` file, you should get instance of injected service from angular's `TestBed`.

```js
describe('login', () => {
   it('sets the state when login is successful', () => {
      // Get the injected instance of AuthService
      const authService = TestBed.inject(AuthService);

      spyOn(authService, 'register').and.returnValue(of(false));

      spyOn(authService, 'login').and.returnValue(
        of({ access_token: 'scdkj2' })
      );
      // Make sure fixture.detectChanges() is not invoked before all spies are setup
      fixture.detectChanges();
      
      ....
    });
  });
```

Comment: Thank you. Is the fixture necessary if I just want to assert on changes in a state and not an element?

Comment: just an FYI so you are aware if you are testing with UI elements

Comment: Ah, got it. Thank you